# Get Reviewer info from Facebook Graph API Rating call

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm facing a weird problem with the Facebook Graph API.

My goal is to get specific Page Ratings in order to display them on a website.

I'm using the JavaScript SDK and followed everything the documentation said about page's access token.

Here is my Facebook Login button in order to get my App authorized by the current user account (in that case it's mine) with correct Admin Role for the Page :

```
<fb:login-button id="fb-login-btn" scope="manage_pages,pages_show_list" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
```

Then I'm getting all the user's Pages with the help of the /me/accounts API call:

```
FB.api('/me/accounts', function(response) {

  if(response && !response.errors) {
    const selectList = document.getElementById('fb-page-list');

    // Populate the list
    response.data.forEach(page => {
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = JSON.stringify({id: page.id, access_token: page.access_token});
      option.text = page.name;
      selectList.appendChild(option);
    });
  }
});
```

So when the client will select a Page name it will get the correct Page's access token in order to make Page specific API call after.

Then the last step is the Page's ratings call:

```
FB.api(
  '/'+ page.id + '/ratings?access_token='+ page.access_token +'&limit=10?fields=reviewer{id,name,picture},rating}',
  function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }
);
```

So, when I execute that query in the Graph API Explorer (which is provided by the Facebook Developer interface) it works perfectly. I get my ratings as:

[Graph API Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmbEP.png)

When I try in a browser, I also get my ratings but only some of the default fields (i.e created_time, review_text, rating).

The reviewer field is a default field. So, I did tried to query without any field parameters and it acts the same.

Initially, I thought that it was about permissions but in the documentation it says that only 'manage_pages' is needed.

How can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same problem here, but with PHP SDK. I asked to the Facebook support center for developers, and they replied quickly. The reason is associated to recent changes and here what they suggested to me, according to the documentation:

"For dev mode apps, 'App users can only access the data of users who have a role on the app.' https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/security Please submit your app for app review and publish your app to access the user info."

I didn't try yet, hope this can fix our problem

Comment: Ok, that make totally sense for me as my App is still in Dev Mode. I do not require the need to submit a review for the moment but if I do, I will update the answer for sure ! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to help you. Instead, in my case, I need all the ratings and related reviewers from a Facebook page and with those platform changes I can't get reviewers anymore unless I publish the App.

Comment: I used facebook graph api for ratings for a page. But it not returns all reviews as on facebook page. like on my facebook page the reviews are 94 and in api it returns 73. Is there any filters for graph api?

Comment: You may need pagination or as a quick workaround I think you can use a property to increase the number of item received (something like LIMIT=1000 in your request). Try to have a glance to the graph API developer tool and check if you receive less reviews also there.

Comment: This was the issue for me too except that I was using `open_graph_story{id,data,from,comments.limit(100){id,created_time,from,message}}`.  Seemingly for no reason my app stopped getting anything for the `from` fields.  It turns out that I had switched my app back into development mode at some point, and as soon as I took my app out of development mode into live it worked.